# Proof that if sets $A$ and $B$ are finited then $A\cup B$ are also finited

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I started with: $\exists x_1,r_1 A \subset K(x_1,r_1) $ and $\exists x_2,r_2 B \subset K(x_2,r_2)$. Let $r=r_1 + r_2 + d(x_1,x_2)$. We want to show that $A\cup B \subset K(x_1,r)$. Let's check if $d(x,x_1) < r$:

1. $x\in A \to d(x,x_1) < r_1 < r$
2. $x\in B \to d(x,x_1) \le d(x,x_2) + d(x_2,x_1) \le r_2 + d(x_2,x_1)  \le r$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: What you mean is $A,B$ bounded not finite. Proof is correct (except line 2. should have a strict inequality).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the proof is correct, BTW, such sets are called **bounded** not "finited" (a non-existent word).

The second line should read:

$$x\in B \to d(x,x_1) \le d(x,x_2) + d(x_2,x_1) < r_2 + d(x_2,x_1)  < r$$

with strict inequalities, of course.